# Backspace event troubles

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener on page 1

```
window.addEventListener("keydown")
```

It's causing me issues where another event listener "keydown" in a dialog on that page 1 is conflicting with the window event listener.

There are two event listeners:

dialog event listener
Page event listener

When I add text to the dialog, the page picks up that keydown. I don't want that. I can't add stopPropagation to the page then the dialog won't get the backspace.

What should I do? Can I replace the window. part to something more specific?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - how the event listeners are added?

Comment: try this [stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: other option: change one keydown to keyup and then try to block them. check event path in console.

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler for the text input, call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from being propagated further to other listeners.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.